# How to compare if any of the elements in a row is same

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to compare whether "any value of" a row is identical to "any value" of the row above -- *regardless* of the order? Below is a very random input data table.

```
DT <- data.table(A=c("a","a","b","d","e","f","h","i","j"),
                 B=c("a","b","c","c","f","g",NA,"j",NA),
                 C=c("a","b","c","b","g","h",NA,NA,NA))

> DT
   A  B  C
1: a  a  a
2: a  b  b
3: b  c  c
4: d  c  b
5: e  f  g
6: f  g  h
7: h NA NA
8: i  j NA
9: j NA NA
```

I would like to add a column D that compares a row with the row above, and compare whether *any* values of the two rows are identical (regardless of the order). So the desired output would be:

```
 > DT
   A  B  C  D
1: a  a  a  0 #No row above to compare; could be either NA or 0
2: a  b  b  1 #row 2 has "a", which is in row 1; returns 1
3: b  c  c  1 #row 3 has "b", which is in row 2; returns 1
4: d  c  b  1 #row 4 has "b" and "c", which are in row 3; returns 1
5: e  f  g  0 #row 5 has nothing that is in row 4; returns 0
6: f  g  h  1 #row 6 has "f" and "g", which are in row 5; returns 1
7: h NA NA  1 #row 7 has "h", which is in row 6; returns 1
8: i  j NA  0 #row 8 has nothing that is in row 7 (NA doesn't count)
9: j NA NA  1 #row 9 has "j", which is in row 8; returns 1 (NA doesn't count)
```

The main idea is that I would like to compare a row (or a vector) with another row (vector), and define two rows to be identical if any of the elements in each row (vector) are.  (without reiterating to compare each element)

Comment: How many rows does your data have? How many unique values do the columns contain as a whole? A convenient way to approach this is with the `crossprod(table())` concept (probably utilizing a `sparseMatrix`) -- e.g. `as.integer(c(FALSE, tcrossprod(table(row(DT), as.matrix(DT)))[cbind(2:nrow(DT), 1:(nrow(DT) - 1))] > 0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a loop-free approach using data.table's joins:

```
DT[, id := 1:.N]
dt <- melt(DT, id.vars = "id")
dt[, id2 := id-1]
dt <- dt[!is.na(value)]
idx <- dt[dt, on = .(id2 = id, value), nomatch=0][, unique(id)]
DT[, `:=`(D = as.integer(id %in% idx), id = NULL)]
```

It looks somewhat complicated but id does perform pretty well with just over a second for a 1-million-row data set with three columns.

Comment: The solution works great on my very large dataset, thanks! But I'm curious what the line `idx <- dt[dt, on = .(id2 = id, value), nomatch=0][, unique(id)] ` is supposed to do? especially what the `on` is for?

Comment: @yongwookLee, that is a self join, i.e. joining dt with itself. The on part specifies that it should join when `id2` is equal to `id` and `value` is equal to `value`. Since `id2` is defined as `id-1` and the original `id` corresponds to the row-number of `DT`, we essentially perform the join only between two consecutive rows containing the same value (and then get the unique row-id's)

Answer (score 4):

We can do this by getting the `lead` rows of the dataset, `paste` each row, check for any pattern in with the `paste`ed rows of original dataset using `grepl` and `Map`, then `unlist` and convert to `integer`

```
DT[, D := {
     v1 <- do.call(paste, .SD)
     v2 <- do.call(paste, c(shift(.SD, type = "lead"), sep="|"))
     v2N <- gsub("NA\\|*|\\|*NA", "", v2)
     v3 <- unlist(Map(grepl, v2N, v1), use.names = FALSE)
     as.integer(head(c(FALSE, v3), -1))        
}]

DT
#   A  B  C D
#1: a  a  a 0
#2: a  b  b 1
#3: b  c  c 1
#4: d  c  b 1
#5: e  f  g 0
#6: f  g  h 1
#7: h NA NA 1
#8: i  j NA 0
#9: j NA NA 1
```

---

Or we can do a `split` and do comparison using `Map`

```
as.integer(c(FALSE, unlist(Map(function(x,y) {
     x1 <- na.omit(unlist(x))
     y1 <- na.omit(unlist(y))
    any(x1 %in% y1 | y1 %in% x1)  },
     split(DT[-nrow(DT)], 1:(nrow(DT)-1)), split(DT[-1], 2:nrow(DT))), use.names = FALSE)))
```

Comment: maybe something a little simpler via `length(unique(unlist(x)))==ncol(x)` ? (I'm not much good at `data.table`, so I'll just leave this here)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks, I think we can change it to more compact `uniqueN(unlist(x))== ncol(x)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is another method. It's probably not advisable on large data.tables as it uses `by=1:nrow(DT)` which tends to be quite slow.

```
DT[, D:= sign(DT[, c(.SD, shift(.SD))][,
   sum(!is.na(intersect(unlist(.SD[, .(A, B, C)]), unlist(.SD[, .(V4, V5, V6)])))),
   by=1:nrow(DT)]$V1)]
```

Here, `[, c(.SD, shift(.SD))]` creates a copy of the data.frame, with the lagged variables included (cbinded). Then the second chain intersects the unlisted variables in the original data.table and the shifted data.table. NAs are assigned 0 and non-NAs are assigned 1 and these results are summed. This operation occurs for each row of the copied data.table. The sum is extracted with `$v1` and is turned into binary (0 and 1) using `sign`.

It returns

```
DT
   A  B  C D
1: a  a  a 0
2: a  b  b 1
3: b  c  c 1
4: d  c  b 1
5: e  f  g 0
6: f  g  h 1
7: h NA NA 1
8: i  j NA 0
9: j NA NA 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do a sapply along the indices (minus the last) of the table:

```
compare <- function(i) {
    row1 <- as.character(DT[i,])
    row2 <- as.character(DT[i+1,])
    return(length(intersect(row1[!is.na(row1)], row2[!is.na(row2)])) > 0)
}

result <- sapply(1:(nrow(DT) - 1), compare)
```

This returns a vector of logicals, so if you prefer to get integers, wrap the output of `compare` in a `as.numeric()`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base` R solution using `intersect`:

```
res <- c(0, sapply(2:nrow(DT), function(i) 
  length(intersect( na.omit(as.character(DT[i,])), na.omit(as.character(DT[i-1,])) ) )>0))

cbind(DT, D=res)
   # A  B  C D
# 1: a  a  a 0
# 2: a  b  b 1
# 3: b  c  c 1
# 4: d  c  b 1
# 5: e  f  g 0
# 6: f  g  h 1
# 7: h NA NA 1
# 8: i  j NA 0
# 9: j NA NA 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution compares the two rows with `%in%` (after `unlist()`):

```
DT[, result:=as.integer(c(NA, sapply(2:DT[,.N], function(i) any(na.omit(unlist(DT[i])) %in% unlist(DT[i-1])))))]
#> DT
#   A  B  C result
#1: a  a  a     NA
#2: a  b  b      1
#3: b  c  c      1
#4: d  c  b      1
#5: e  f  g      0
#6: f  g  h      1
#7: h NA NA      1
#8: i  j NA      0
#9: j NA NA      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of `intersect` and `mapply` you could do:

```
#list of unique elements in each row
tableList = apply(DT,1,function(x) unique(na.omit(x)))

#a lagged list to be compared with above list
tableListLag = c(NA,tableList[2:length(tableList)-1])

#find common elements using intersect function
#if length > 0 implies common elements hence set value as 1 else 0
DT$D = mapply(function(x,y) ifelse(length(intersect(x,y))>0,1,0) ,tableList,tableListLag,
             SIMPLIFY = TRUE)


DT
#   A  B  C D
#1: a  a  a 0
#2: a  b  b 1
#3: b  c  c 1
#4: d  c  b 1
#5: e  f  g 0
#6: f  g  h 1
#7: h NA NA 1
#8: i  j NA 0
#9: j NA NA 1
```